# How to change temp directory for SSIS packages so it does not use the C drive (instead of C:\windows\temp use E drive or something else)

Tags: c#, ssis, .net-assembly, temp

I'm deploying an SSIS package to a SQL Server and I need to set it up so that it does not use the C drive.  Currently there are some assembly files ('C:\Windows\TEMP.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs') that the program needs but due to permission issues the package is not allowed to access the C drive.  Is there a way to set where the temp folders go?

Comment: Have you tried changing the system environment temp directory on the server?

Comment: I recall this issut from a long time ago. Using a script task required admin access to `C\Windows\Temp`. I never found a solution so I stopped using the script task. This may not be an option for you though.